# Getting value from textvariable (entry widget)

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a simple form box, ultimately to place data in a database. Right now I am simply testing it with `puts` statements, as follows:

```
package require Tk

wm title . "Add"
grid [ttk::frame .c -padding "3 3 12 12"] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nwes
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1; grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1

grid [ttk::label .c.idlbl -width 7 -text "id"] -column 1 -row 1 -sticky we
grid [ttk::entry .c.id -width 7 -textvariable id] -column 2 -row 1 -sticky we

grid [ttk::label .c.txtlbl -text "text"] -column 1 -row 2 -sticky w
grid [ttk::entry .c.txt -width 7 -textvariable text] -column 2 -row 2 -sticky we


grid [ttk::button .c.calc -text "Add!" -command db_add] -column 1 -row 3 -sticky w

foreach w [winfo children .c] {grid configure $w -padx 5 -pady 5}
focus .c.id


proc db_add {} {
    set id $::id
    set text $::text
    puts $id
    puts $text
}
```

My question: why do I need to do `set` into another variable name, before I can do anything with the value? Why can I not just do `puts $::id`?

I have tried `puts expr{$::id}`, which gives an output like `expr{Whatever Text Was Entered}`, leaving me unsure why the `expr` does not go away. It seems my concept of variables in TCL is very murky at the moment.

Comment: It seems your knowledge of invoking commands is lacking. Tcl has only [12 rules of syntax](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), have a read through them.

Comment: You want `puts [expr $::id]`

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `puts $::id`, but until you have entered text into the entry fields, the variables don't exist. You can initialize them in parallel with creating the widgets, or test them for existence:

```
if {![info exists ::id]} {
    set ::id {}
}
puts \$::id=$::id
```